# ffmpeg -to option acting like -t option?

Tags: ffmpeg

The following command is producing a video of the exact length of the -to parameter:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:06:26 -i fftestinput.mp4 -to 00:06:38 -r 29.97 fftestoutput.mp4
```

Again, the final product is a very nice video of length 6:38.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. `-to` looks at the timestamps. And input `ss` resets them to zero from the seek point. Either use `-ss` as output option (after `-i`) or calculate and use duration `-t`. The former will slow operation, as it performs a slow seek (decode and discard till inpoint).

Comment: Thank you, Mulvya.  That now makes sense.  I should have my code calculate the duration and do it that way.